# plagiarism vs copyright violation?

Tags: meaning

Danielle writes an essay that’s she worked very hard on and sends it off to an academic journal after she finishes it.  The journal sends her comments on the essay, including one that claims her research has already been done and that she can’t publish her work, because another person already has.  If she does publish it, would it fall under plagiarism or copyright violation?

Comment: Maybe neither. What is your understanding of the meaning of the word "plagiarism"?

Comment: Plagiarism is a scholarly and literary concept, and argued over by authors; copyright is a legal and political concept, and argued over by attorneys and regulators. Something can be one or either or both or neither depending on the context, the controlling political authority, and the forums where the aggrieved litigate their accusation.

Comment: plagiarism is stealing ideas from authors. Some plagiarism may be copyright infringement but not all copyright infringement is plagiarism. Copyright infringement could be forgetting to cite a source but using quote marks.

Answer (score 1):

*Plagiarism* is copying another writer's work (concepts and/or expression) and passing it off as your own. This is considered a kind of academic misconduct, but is generally not prohibited by any law (depending on your jurisdiction).

*Copyright infringement* (at least in the US) is copying someone else's previously written expression of an idea. It doesn't apply to facts, ideas, or concepts, but to the specific words used to express them. The exact definition of copyright infringement is a matter of law, and therefore varies from jurisdiction to jurisdiction (but is also to some extent agreed between countries by certain treaties).

> The journal sends her comments on the essay, including one that claims her research has already been done and that she can’t publish her work,

This situation is not necessarily either plagiarism or copyright infringement. The writer might have independently come up with their ideas (therefore this is not plagiarism, even if someone else had the same ideas before) and used their own words to express them (therefore this is not copyright infringement), and yet the journal could still decline to publish the submission because it doesn't present sufficiently new ideas.

Comment: Not every set of previously written words are protected by copyright, so there's a third option.

Comment: @ColleenV, sure but that's a pretty subtle point (i.e. when does a combination of words not represent a creative expression). If the question wants to get into that level of detail, it should be moved to [Law Stackexchange](http://law.stackexchange.com). The details probably also depend on what country you are in.

Comment: How do you know given the lack of detail in the original question? The second author could have properly cited the second author, which is not plagiarism.

Comment: @ColleenV, this is a language question. I answered with a description of how the words are distinguished from each other. I also said the situation described does  **not necessarily** fit either of the two terms.

Comment: @ColleenV, where did I say I know that the described situation fits either of the terms asked about?

Comment: What is the language question? The difference between plagiarism and copyright violation? How is that not answerable by a dictionary? Is this a word or phrase request? What kind of sentence is the author looking to use such a word in? My point is simply that you are doing a lot of guessing about what the asker is looking for when the asker should probably be adding more detail to their question.

Comment: @ColleenV, Sometimes when you read dictionary definitions of two related terms, it's difficult to understand what's the important distinction between them. In this case the terms involved have much more meaning to them than can be expressed in a couple of sentences in a dictionary. So I don't think it's a leap to interpret the question as being "what's the important distinction between these two terms and how do they apply to my situation?"